# Verify what css hover state is activated

Tags: css, hover

I have a site where the background-image jumps up on hover state and I can't for the life of me find the specific css that does this.

I'm able to get to the "offending" link and give it a border and change the padding and margin. The problem is that firebug and chrome inspect does not show me what happens on the hover state.

So I want a way to see what additions to the normal css state happens on :hover.

Any pointers?

(P.S. IE 8 doesn't have this issue - ie no jumping of background image)

Answer (score 0):

Try using the Inspect function in [FireBug](http://getfirebug.com/) to focus in on the element in question. It will show you all related CSS, including any CSS that is related to :hover. You can also see in this way what changes happen to the elements CSS (and any other DOM attribute) when you hover your mouse.

In case the changes are coming from some JavaScript, try out the [Visual Event](http://www.sprymedia.co.uk/article/Visual+Event) bookmarklet. Activating it on the page will let you see all events that are tied to the element in question.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply, but visual event show's nothing is going on. And firebug inspect element does not give me any info regarding :hover. 

That's why I don't get it - I suddenly have no idea what's going on with my object...

Comment: not really since I don't know what part of the css is kicking in. I'm using aeZ publish cms system with a lot of stanard code and creating a design extension. So something is doing something.... I just want to know how to spot it...

Comment: Right - thanks for your help and input - especially the link to Visual Event - that will be usefull. I found the offending css atleast: background-position: right top; I'll leave this question open if someone has a :hover tool to check what attributes changes.